# will breaking not used anymore RSA codes in the future affect privacy?

Tags: cryptography, security

just read and watch some stuff on how RSA works.
main idea seems to be if someone steals your communication he cannot decode it anyway.

but let's say someone steals it and keeps it along with current RSA-1024 used.
if in 10 years he will be able to break this RSA can he decode our communication and passwords from 10 years ago?

Comment: What makes you think they couldn't?

Answer (score 2):

Anybody who knows the cyphertext and the decryption key can decrypt the message. It doesn't matter how they obtained the cyphertext or the key, or how much time has elapsed since the message was encrypted; anyone who has both of those things can decrypt.